# I need help sending excel attachment from memory Mailgun

Tags: python, openpyxl, mailgun

Im trying to send an email with an Excel attachment using Python and the Mailgun Rest API.

The idea is to create the excel file using openpyxl and then send the excel workbook that is stored in python memory as an attachment.

Many thanks in advance

```
import workbook from openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()

ws = wb.active

ws['A1'] = 42

def send_simple_message(wb):
  return requests.post(
    "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxf04fcce3c4dc46c987c92f3a967e7f9c.mailgun.org/messages",
    files = [("attachment", ("test.xlsx", wb))],
    auth = ("api", "3701ba6d2b1ad202e76a4322a80c7600-87cdd4445-897e02b1"),
    data = {
      "from": "Excited User <mailgun@sandboxf04brede3c4dc46c987c92f3a967e7f9c.mailgun.org>",
      "to": "exampleemail@gmail.com",
      "subject": "Hello",
      "text": 'hello'
    })

send_simple_message(wb)
```

it resulted in the following traceback error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-39-5dc97cf501dc>", line 1, in <module>
    send_simple_message(wb)

  File "<ipython-input-37-fc3ec9cbb304>", line 9, in send_simple_message
    "text": 'hello'})

  File "/Users/willpeebles/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 112, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/willpeebles/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/willpeebles/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 504, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)

  File "/Users/willpeebles/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 436, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),

  File "/Users/willpeebles/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 305, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)

  File "/Users/willpeebles/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 499, in prepare_body
    (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)

  File "/Users/willpeebles/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 158, in _encode_files
    fdata = fp.read()

AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'read'
```

How should I change the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workbook is not a file-like object. requests's file expects a file-like object, so you need to convert the workbook to a file-like object first. You can use io.BytesIO to create an in-memory file-like object:

```
from io import BytesIO

...

bio = BytesIO()
wb.save(bio)
bio.seek(0)
send_simple_message(bio)
```